# Getting started with Cordova - Installing Android SDK issues

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

Im trying to get set up with Cordona and need to install the Android SDK.  I have followed the instructions on the Cordona website (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html and https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) but am stuck when it comes to installing the Android SDK.

I have selected the link to download Android SDK and the only option seems to be to download Android Studio.  So after downloading this I am supposed to add the path to the Android SDK to my system environment variables, however I cannot find an SDK folder.  So I have added 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio' for the **ANDROID_HOME** variable and have also added 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin' onto **PATH** (both are under "user variables").  This doesn't appear to be working for me.  Can someone tell me where the SDK folder is?

Please someone help get me started :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the exe to install Android Studio, the SDK should also have been installed. For me it was under: C:\pathToMyUserFolder\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

If you just downloaded the zip-folder, did you already download the sdk tools? https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

This folder is the sdk folder you need to set as ANDROID_HOME

Comment: Yes I downloaded the exe from that exact page and the andriod studio files have been saved to:  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio.  I can't find the SDK folder anywhere.  I can't find an AppData folder either :(

Comment: OK AppData is normaly under your user-folder (same level as e.g. downloads or documents or music). But it's most likely hidden so you have to activate that in the windows explorer. Or just run the installation again and click next until you reach the screen where the folder is set and copy that.

Comment: Yes, you're right that folder was hidden.  Many thanks for that.  Don't suppose you know of any good step by step tutorials to get a basic app running?

Comment: Normally the android developer page is a very good documented one: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: OK thanks, will look at that, although I am building with Cordona so that I can build an app for multiple platforms not just the andriod.

Comment: Don't you mean cordova? Then I would recommend the IDE ionic recommends: https://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs?wt.mc_id=o~display~ionic~dn948185